# Bar plot where y labels add up the more they appear and x labels group together if they have the same name?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have a dataframe that looks identical to the one below, where each movie has an actor name and then a 1 or 0 depending if the actor is in the movie.

| index | movie_title | actors | in_movie |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Exodus | name1 | 0 |
| 1 | Exodus | name2 | 1 |
| 2 | Alien | name3 | 0 |
| 2 | Alien | name4 | 0 |
| 3 | Ghost | name5 | 1 |
| 3 | Ghost | name6 | 1 |
| 3 | Ghost | name7 | 1 |

I would like to make a bar plot that has each name of the movie once in the x axis, and then the y axis representing the amount of in_movie items, so in Ghost for example, it would be a three since three actors are in it.

I have tried using the code below but get an absolute mess of a plot, where the x axis repeats the movie_title variable instead of grouping them and the in_movie variable is just 0 or 1

```
df.plot.bar(x = 'movie_title', y = 'in_movie')
```

What I would like to do instead is that the x axis has only one instance of each movie, and the y axis adds itself, so Ghost for example will have a 3 on the y axis.

Is there any smart way of doing this so it makes sense, I can't figure out how to do it the correct way?

Here is an example of the csv if it makes more sense to see:

```
,index,movie_title,actors,in_movie
0,1,Exodus,name1,0
1,1,Exodus,name2,1
2,2,Alien,name3,0
3,2,Alien,name4,0
4,3,Ghost,name5,1
5,3,Ghost,name6,1
6,3,Ghost,name7,1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first use [`groupby.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) to get the count of actors in the movie:

```
df.groupby('movie_title')['in_movie'].sum().plot.bar()
```

To consider the possibility of duplicated actors within a movie:

```
(df.groupby(['movie_title', 'actors'])['in_movie'].max()
   .groupby(level=0).sum().plot.bar()
)
```

Output:

[image]

If you don't care about the 'in_movie' variable:

```
df.groupby('movie_title')['actors'].nunique().plot.bar()
```

[image]

Comment: Using groupby works perfectly, thanks!